# How to properly use the jQuery location.reload() function when a large and small image are swapped at a specified size

Tags: javascript, jquery

When the browser window size is <= 1023px a large image is swapped with a small img and if the window is >= 1024px the reverse occurs. How do I incorporate a single reload when these conditions are met. So far, I've gotten it to reload constantly or gotten an error in the console. I'm still a newbie where js and jQ are concerned. Thanks!

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
      $(function() {     
        if($(window).width() <= 1023) {
          $("img").each(function() {
            $(this).attr("src", 
$(this).attr("src").replace("images/big/carousel/", "images/small/carousel/"));         

          });
        }    
      });    

      $(function() {     
        if($(window).width() >= 1024) {
          $("img").each(function() {
            $(this).attr("src", 
$(this).attr("src").replace("images/small/carousel/", "images/big/carousel/"));         

          });
        }    
      }); 
</script>
```

Comment: If you only want to change the img loaded, you won't need to use the `location.reload()` function. At the moment, what is it supposed to change depending on the width ? Only the image ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Maincore. Yes just image swapping between larger screens and mobile. What I'm noticing when I change my browser window is the image resolution doesn't automatically swap without a refresh. So just need to figure out how to reload once when browser window hits those breeakpoints.